# Removing HtmlElement objects programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control, dom

In a `WebBrowser` control, how do I remove `HtmlElement` objects?  There are no methods in the `HtmlElement` class to accomplish this.  As a workaround, I can create a "dummy" `HtmlElement` (without inserting it into the `HtmlDocument`), into which I then insert (via `AppendChild`) the `HtmlElement` objects to be removed.  This feels like a hack.  Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. I want to retain the `HtmlElement` in memory to be used later, not simply destroy it (which is what setting its parent's `innerHtml` to an empty string would do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this WebControl Heritance, with loads of feature: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

You could add a remove method to del element by id.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the element by setting its outerhtml to an empty string.

elem.OuterHtml = ""

I hope this is what you were looking for.

gm

Comment: Doesn't [always] work with Internet Explorer 6. The BASE tag, for instance, resists this method.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml (from .Net tab)

```
using Microsoft.mshtml;
....
{
...
    // To Remove     
    HTMLDocumentClass htmldoc = wbCtrl.Document.DomDocument as HTMLDocumentClass;
    IHTMLDOMNode node = htmldoc.getElementById("xBar") as IHTMLDOMNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me able to figure it out. My code works with: HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument; IHTMLElement tmpElement = htmlDoc.getElementById("xBar"); IHTMLDOMNode tmpNode = (IHTMLDOMNode)tmpElement; tmpNode.parentNode.removeChild(tmpNode);

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the dynamic keyword to save the explicit casting of everything, but then you don't get compile time verification that the methods exist.

Answer (score 2):

The only other way I know is to change the parent's [`InnerHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's a method called `IHTMLDOMNode::removeNode` which looks like the "official" way to do this, but this is unmanaged code in `mshtml.dll`.  I'm looking for something more suitable for C#.