# Loading page to WebBrowser control while skipping HTML elements by ID?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, browser

I am trying to load a certain page though WebBrowser control while avoiding unnecessary advertisement banners which load in DIV element called 'tb'.

How can I do this? I have done some googling and found an example using mshtml reference but I can't make it work from this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218875

Any ideas?

Why wouldn't this work?

```
using System;
using mshtml;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Client : Form
    {
        public Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            HTMLDocumentClass htmldoc = wbBrowser.Document.DomDocument as HTMLDocumentClass;
            IHTMLDOMNode node = htmldoc.getElementById("tb") as IHTMLDOMNode;
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' does not contain a definition for 'getElementById' and no extension method 'getElementById' accepting a first argument of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And:

> Interop type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
IHTMLDocument3 htmldoc = wbCtrl.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument3;
IHTMLDOMNode node = htmldoc.getElementById("xBar") as IHTMLDOMNode;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```